# Make two divs of variable width adjacent and centered at the same time

Tags: html, css, glyphicons

I am stuck on a rather tricky CSS problem.  This is what the banner for one our pages currently looks like:

[image]

And here is the relevant HTML code:

```
<div style="width: 50%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 auto; line-height: 40px">
    <div style="float: right">
        <i class="glyphicon project-switcher glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4 style="white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden;
                   text-overflow: ellipsis">Some Project Title</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is space between the project title and the drop down menu glyphicon, which looks like small downward-pointing white arrow.

What we would like to achieve is to have the project title immediately adjacent to the glyphicon, but also have the title and glyphicon themselves centered in the middle of the screen.  Something like this is what we want:

[image]

I have read a number of posts here on SO regarding making one div fixed with the other flexible, but I couldn't find a way to apply that to the present case.  Actually, I don't even know how to formulate a solution to this problem, which is why I am asking for help.

Comment: You should use *Flexbox* Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have look at below snippet

```html
<div style="width: 50%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 auto; line-height: 40px; text-align:center; border:1px solid #000">
    
    <div style=" display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; max-width:90%">
        <h4 style="white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden;
                   text-overflow: ellipsis;">Some Project TSome Project TSome Project TSome Project TSome Project TSome Project TSome Project TSome Project TSome Project T</h4>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
        <i class="glyphicon project-switcher glyphicon-chevron-down">i</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This appeared to work on desktop, but when testing in mobile it didn't work, and also this prevents the ellipsis from working.

Comment: Can you show me the output on mobile, also you have to give fixed width to `h4` to make ellipsis work

Comment: This is one of the requirements that the `<h4>` can have variable width, because we don't know how long the title might be.  We want the title to take up all available space, except for the glyph.

Answer (score 0):

try like this, it may work...

```
     <div style="width: 50%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 auto; line-height:   40px">


        <h4 style="white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden;
                   text-overflow: ellipsis">Some Project Title <i class="glyphicon project-switcher glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></h4>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: flex; justify-content: center;` will center the 2 elements in the middle (centered horizontally). And `align-items: center` will center them vertically.

Then you can use `order` on the children to re-order the elements so that the glyph is on the right, even though it comes before the `h4` in the markup. Or you could just re-arrange those 2 elements in your HTML.

```html
<div style="width: 50%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 auto; line-height: 40px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
  <div style="order: 1;">
    <i class="glyphicon project-switcher glyphicon-chevron-down">(glyph)</i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4 style="white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis">Some Project Title</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, this worked in desktop mode (and it obviously works in your demo), but it had problems on mobile view.  Specifically, the title and glyph were getting cutoff on mobile view.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen do you still want help? Looks like you've already accepted an answer.

Comment: The other answer worked for me, but thanks for posting.  The thing is, I have a mobile view.