# Query to select 2 most recent dated records per grouping

Tags: sql, r

Using R, I want to grab the two most recently dated entries for each UserID, assuming there is 1 or more entries per UserID.

The key elements of my data would be an identifier (UserID), and a date, that is of type date.

Thank you.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MS 2014 I believe. I am game for using sqldf or sqlquery from the rodbc package.

Comment: I gave you a query below.  For the R side of things, any tutorial should get it done.

Comment: Thanks. I am working it out now, noting that it is similar to a previous attempt. I will comment below your suggested solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, which has the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function, you can try this query:

```
SELECT t.UserID, t.date, ...other columns
FROM
(
    SELECT UserID, date, ...other columns,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 2
```

Comment: Uh, wow! That worked like a champ and the syntax you specified makes sense to my feeble mind. I spent the better part of the day going back to this one. I even see where I goofed up. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help you out.

Comment: I just started a very different gig analyzing data (20 years of IT systems mgmt before) and decided to teach myself R. This site and the people who jump in to help are a blessing.

Comment: @Scottieie I use it myself, q.v. the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406876/make-two-divs-of-variable-width-adjacent-and-centered-at-the-same-time) I asked yesterday.